# Singular vs plural + per + noun?

Tags: paraphrasing

I would like to paraphrase a sentence:

> "This is how the costs of each course should be."

So my idea was:

> "This is how the price/prices per course should be."

**What are the differences between singular + per vs. plural + per?**

Or

**If you have better paraphrases, you're very welcome to share them.**

`Thank you very much :)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got the original sentence, but it's odd in two ways.

1. The "costs" of "each". This implies that each course has more than one cost. This is possible. There may be a cost for full-time students and a different cost for part-time students, etc. But I wonder if the intent was not that each course has one cost. There are many costs, but only one for each course.
2. "how the costs should be" Normally we would say "what the costs should be" or "how much the costs should be". "How" indicates a method, like "how to bake a cake" or "how we will find our way out". A cost does not normally have a method. It has an amount. Oh, another possibility is that the writer meant, "how the costs will be determined".

As to your paraphrase, the most likely wording is, "This is what the price per course should be." Other wordings are possible depending on just what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got the original sentence, but it's odd in two ways.

1. The "costs" of "each". This implies that each course has more than one cost. This is possible. There may be a cost for full-time students and a different cost for part-time students, etc. But I wonder if the intent was not that each course has one cost. There are many costs, but only one for each course.
2. "how the costs should be" Normally we would say "what the costs should be" or "how much the costs should be". "How" indicates a method, like "how to bake a cake" or "how we will find our way out". A cost does not normally have a method. It has an amount. Oh, another possibility is that the writer meant, "how the costs will be determined".

As to your paraphrase, the most likely wording is, "This is what the price per course should be." Other wordings are possible depending on just what you're trying to say.

By [Jay](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/803/jay).

---

*Comments:*

- price per course makes no sense (as I told you before). – michael.hor257k yesterday
- Can you suggest me any other word forms please? @michael.hor257k, I'm still curious why "10 dollars per person" is acceptable, but "price per course" is not? They even have the same word orders "10 dollars" = "price" and "person = course". – hbtpoprock 19 hours ago
- Because 10 dollars is a quantity, and price is not. I cannot suggest any alternatives, because I don't know what you're trying to say. – michael.hor257k 19 hours ago
- But "10 dollars" is actually a price, isn't it? LOL I'm trying to paraphrase it, that's all because it's a part of my exam given by my teacher. @michael.hor257k – hbtpoprock 19 hours ago
- No, 10 dollars is an amount. It is not the same as price. When I pay you 10 dollars, I give you an amount of money; I don't give you a price. – michael.hor257k 19 hours ago
- What if I use ". . . the price for every course . . .", does this make more sense? @michael.hor257k – hbtpoprock 19 hours ago
- It depends on the missing context. In some contexts, it could work. And you'd probably prefer to say the price of every course in most of them. – michael.hor257k 19 hours ago
- And "the price" should be singular since a course has only one price otherwise a course will have many prices, right? @michael.hor257k – hbtpoprock 18 hours ago
- Yes. Unless you have multiple prices per course (see what I did there?) - for example, one price for takeaway and another price to dine in. – michael.hor257k 18 hours ago
- Ty, @michael.hor257k, I appreciated it – hbtpoprock 18 hours ago

Comment: What's wrong with "price per course"? People say such things all the time. Each course has a price. There is a price per course. Your statement that a price is not a quantity is inaccurate. If I ask, "What is the price?", someone might well answer, "Ten dollars." Yes, we cannot necessarily substitute "ten dollars" in any sentence that has the word "price" and have it make sense. Like sure, if I pay you $10, we don't say "I gave you the price" but "I paid you the price".

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, a course could have two prices if there are different prices under different circumstances, like one price for in-state students and another price for out-of-state students, or one price for regular students and another price for children of faculty members, etc. That may or may not be what is intended here.

Comment: So, what he said is wrong? @Jay

Comment: Hi, @michael.hor257k. I need you here please.

Comment: I disagree with @michael.hor257k's comments, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between singular and plural is what it usually is: if there's only one, use singular, if there's more than one, use plural. So if all the prices are the same, then there's only one price, so it should be "price". If different courses have different prices, then it should be "prices".

Comment: Let's say, there're 3 different courses, and they have 3 different prices for each course. So the sentence would be "This is what the **prices** per course should be.", right?